# sieve or eratosthenes calculator -- running into memory issues and crashing with numbers >=1,000,000

Tags: c++, memory, crash, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm not exactly sure why this is. I tried changing the variables to long long, and I even tried doing a few other things -- but its either about the inefficiency of my code (it literally does the whole process of finding all primes up to the number, then checking against the number to see if its divisible by that prime -- very inefficient, but its my first attempt at this and I feel pretty accomplished having it work at all....)

Or the fact that it overflows the stack. Im not sure where it is exactly, but all I know is that it MUST be related to memory and the way its dealing with the number.

If I had to guess, Id say its a memory issue happening when it is dealing with the prime number generation up to that number -- thats where it dies even if I remove the check against the input number.

I'll post my code -- just be aware, I didnt change long long back to int in a few places, and I also have a SquareRoot Variable that is not used, because it was supposed to try and help memory efficiency but was not effective the way I tried to do it. I Just never deleted it. I will clean up the code when and if I can successfully finish it.

As far as I am aware though, it DOES work pretty reliably for 999,999 and down, I actually checked it up against other calculators of the same type and it seemingly does generate the proper answers.

If anyone can help or explain what I screwed up here, your helping a guy trying to learn on his own without any school or anything. so its appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

void sieve(int ubound, int primes[]);

int main()
{
    long long n;
    int i;
    std::cout << "Input Number: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    if (n < 2) {
        return 1;
    }

    long long upperbound = n;
    int A[upperbound];
    int SquareRoot = sqrt(upperbound);
    sieve(upperbound, A);

    for (i = 0; i < upperbound; i++) {
        if (A[i] == 1 && upperbound % i == 0) {
            std::cout << " " << i << " ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void sieve(int ubound, int primes[])
{
    long long i, j, m;

    for (i = 0; i < ubound; i++) {
        primes[i] = 1;
    }

    primes[0] = 0, primes[1] = 0;

    for (i = 2; i < ubound; i++) {
        for(j = i * i; j < ubound; j += i) {
            primes[j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: " I Just never deleted it. I will clean up the code when and if I can successfully finish it." - No, do it now.

Comment: int A[upperbound]; Thats bad. You don't know the size of your array at compilation time.

Comment: [MCVE] please! Leave out any irrelevant stuff.

Comment: `long long upperbound = n;  int A[upperbound];` -- This is not legal C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used legal C++ constructs instead of non-standard [variable length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c), your code will run (whether it produces the correct answers is another question).

The issue is more than likely that you're exceeding the limits of the stack when you declare arrays with a million or more elements.

Therefore instead of this:

```
long long upperbound = n;
A[upperbound];
```

Use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
#include <vector>
//...
long long upperbound = n;
std::vector<int> A(upperbound);
```

and then:

```
sieve(upperbound, A.data());
```

The `std::vector` does not use the stack space to allocate its elements (unless you have written an allocator for it that uses the stack).

As a matter of fact, you don't even need to pass `upperbound` to `sieve`, as a `std::vector` knows its own size by calling the `size()` member function.  But I leave that as an exercise.

[Live example using 2,000,000](http://ideone.com/Kz7KSq)

Comment: I deeply appreciate all these comments -- I realize how bad the code is. I am just getting back into this after a LONG hiatus where I quit. I never used vectors, and knew I was doing things I shouldnt be (i.e. getting around the rules of C++ and tricking it into taking an array of unknown size -- it took a little work to break that rule lol) I also knew I was overflowing the stack and should probably switch to a vector...

but I never used vectors!!! well its a good learning experience to fix it as much as it was to write what i already did. so I will go fix it today. just wasnt sure itd work

Comment: I do very much appreciate it. you showed me something extraordinarily useful, and Id probably have to sit and read books for awhile to come to the same conclusion on my own.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, read and apply PaulMcKenzie's advice. That's the most important thing. I'm only addressing some teeny bits of your question that remained open.

It seems that you are trying to factor the number that you misleadingly called `upperbound`. The mysterious role of the square root of this number is related to this fact: if the number is composite at all - and hence can be computed as the product of some prime factors - then the smallest of these prime factors cannot be greater than the square root of the number. In fact, only one factor can possibly be greater, all others cannot exceed the square root.

However, in its present form your code cannot draw advantage from this fact. The trial division loop as it stands now has to run up to `number_to_be_factored / 2` in order not to miss any factors because its body looks like this:

```
if (sieve[i] == 1 && number_to_be_factored % i == 0) {
   std::cout << " " << i << " ";
}
```

You can factor much more efficiently if you refactor your code a bit: when you have found the smallest prime factor p of your number then the remaining factors to be found must be precisely those of `rest = number_to_be_factored / p` (or `n = n / p`, if you will), and none of the remaining factors can be smaller than p. However, don't forget that p might occur more than once as a factor.

During any round of the proceedings you only need to consider the prime factors between p and the square root of the current number; if none of those primes divides the current number then it must be prime. To test whether p exceeds the square root of some number n you can use `if (p * p > n)`, which is computationally more efficient that actually computing the square root.

Hence the square root occurs in two different roles:

- the square root of the number to be factored limits the amount of sieving that needs to be done
- during the trial division loop, the square root of the current number gives an upper bound for the highest prime factor that you need to consider

That's two faces of the same coin but two different usages in the actual code.

Note: once you got your code working by applying PaulMcKenzie's advice, you might also to consider posting over on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: its not so mysterious what the square root does to me. I understand the math -- but in the process of trying to code the application I ran into issues and didnt use it. I knew it was going to be used in the final result, so I commented it out and saved that piece.

although you have answered a lot of questions too -- both of you! I was going to do a rewrite trying to get around types by using classes, but what you guys said helps a lot more than stumbling in the dark.

Im going to go back to college for this, but until then your helping me learn a lot! thank you all!!!

Comment: I just hope you all realize, I know im doing stuff wrong. Im day 3 in on restarting to learn to code in C++ -- I started up again and quit after reaching a problem in a game I was making a half year ago, and I actually restarted at that point from when I was 12!!!

I failed on a collision detection system and gave up programming as a kid, but I really want to get back into it as an adult and maybe even make a career of it. My goal is to learn as much as I can on my own and with help online until I can get into college again I just got off drugs and finished rehab & I figure teachers wouldhelp.

Comment: oh and about it appearing more than once as a factor, the function sieve should be preventing this --   for(i=2;i<ubound;i++)
        {
        for(j=i*i; j<ubound;j+=i)
            {
                primes[j]=0;
            }
        }

the primes[j] for statement should be setting the flag to false for all multiples of i, thus removing them from the list. unless im wrong

I took pauls advice, fixed that, and cleaned up the code a lot -- using better variable names and less useless variables. after I finish making your advice work I will post the fixed working code just to show I did fix it

Comment: @spiroth10: I meant that a prime can occur more than once in the **factorisation** of a number; your original code lists each factor prime only once, even if it actually occurs squared or cubed or whatnot. As such it does not compute a factorisaton; it performs the slightly different task of listing all prime factors.